# Issue with injecting dynamic template to a popup component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a template defined like below:

```
<ng-template #tmpl let-name>
    <div>hello</div>
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
</ng-template>
```

If I pass the context to this template from the view, it works fine.

```
<div style="color: red">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="tmpl" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: 'angular'}"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Shows both hello and angular text.

But when I am trying to show the same template in a popup when clicked on the 'show popup' button, I am only seeing the static text 'hello' where as the text from context 'angular' is not being shown.

Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("tmpl", { read: TemplateRef, static: false }) tmpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private readonly modalService: ModalService) {}

  showPopup() {
    const modalData = {id: "modal-1", headline: "Modal Header"};
    this.modalService.open(this.tmpl, modalData);
  }
}
```

Modal service:

```
import {
  ApplicationRef,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ComponentRef,
  Inject,
  Injectable,
  Injector,
  OnDestroy,
  TemplateRef,
  Type
} from "@angular/core";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";
import { ModalComponent } from "./modal.component";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ModalService {
  modalComponent: ComponentRef<ModalComponent>;

  constructor(
    private _appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private _cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _injector: Injector,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ) {}

  open<C>(content: TemplateRef<any>, modal: any): ComponentRef<any> {
    this.closeModal();

    const viewRef = content.createEmbeddedView({ $implicit: "angular" });
    const contentNodes = [viewRef.rootNodes];
    console.log(contentNodes);

    const factory = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent);

    this.modalComponent = factory.create(this._injector, contentNodes);
    this.modalComponent.instance.modalData = modal;
    this.modalComponent.instance.openModal();
    this.modalComponent.hostView.detectChanges();

    const { nativeElement } = this.modalComponent.location;
    this.document.body.appendChild(nativeElement);

    return this.modalComponent;
  }

  closeModal() {
    if (this.modalComponent) {
      this._appRef.detachView(this.modalComponent.hostView);
      this.modalComponent.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

Modal Component:

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  Output,
  ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-modal",
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="modalDisplay" #modal class="modal" [id]="modalData?.id">
      <h1>{{modalData?.headline}}</h1>
      <div class="modal__body">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .modal {
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }
  `]
})
export class ModalComponent {
  modalDisplay = false;

  @Input() modalData: any;
  @ViewChild("modal", { read: ElementRef, static: false }) element: ElementRef;

  public openModal() {
    this.modalDisplay = true;
  }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I have also created a quick dirty example in Stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-template-popup

I am sure I am missing out on a silly thing. Could someone help me out on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I was missing here is to detectChanges on viewRef after dynamically adding content into the template using context in 'model.service.ts'

```
const viewRef = content.createEmbeddedView({ $implicit: "angular" });
viewRef.detectChanges();
```

I had actually posted a separate question on this by creating a simple example - [Getting content of dynamic templates in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61970568/getting-content-of-dynamic-templates-in-component)

And as suggested there, I just added detectChanges on viewRef and now it's working fine

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to set the {{name}} throw template context? Why don't you set name like a class property in your Component.

The template context is used when you must to include a template in other place, but sending the variables as parameters.

I don't know if it your case, but in your example that will works fine, and remove all logic in your service to inject that value.

Good luck

Comment: Sorry but I want to inject the templates in the component dynamically and I don't see any alternate method to do so.