# Getting content of dynamic templates in component

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the template:

```
<button (click)="loadTemplate()">Load Template</button>
<ng-template #tmpl let-name>
    <h2>hello</h2>
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
</ng-template>
```

Here is the component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("tmpl", { read: TemplateRef, static: false }) tmpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  loadTemplate() {
    const viewRef = this.tmpl.createEmbeddedView({ $implicit: "angular" })
    alert('content for static h2 element: ' + viewRef.rootNodes[0].textContent)
    alert('content for dynamic h2 element: ' + viewRef.rootNodes[1].textContent)
  }
}
```

When I am logging 'viewRef.rootNodes', I could see the static text 'hello' but the dynamic text 'angular' which I am passing through implicit context is missing.

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-template-context

Is there anything I am missing out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the fact that dynamic data requires change detection cycle to happen:

```
const viewRef = this.tmpl.createEmbeddedView({ $implicit: "angular" });
viewRef.detectChanges(); // try adding this
alert('content for static h2 element: ' + viewRef.rootNodes[0].textContent)
alert('content for dynamic h2 element: ' + viewRef.rootNodes[1].textContent)
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-template-context-u6me6z?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**